# Possible to %include file in Mako whether file exists or not?

Tags: python, mako

I'm using `<%include file="special_message.html" />` to include any required special message (eg a message about system downtime) on a page.

I'd like to be able to turn the message on by putting the message HTML into the `special_message.html` file and turn it off by simply deleting the file.

If I remove the file, however, Mako fails with a `cannot locate template` message.  Is there any way (short of using an empty file) to tell Mako to simply include nothing if the `%include` file is not found?

Answer (score 0):

This raw Python block may do the trick...

```
<%
    from mako.exceptions import TemplateLookupException

    try:
        tmpl = self.get_template("special_message.html")
    except TemplateLookupException:
        pass
    else:
        tmpl.render_context(context)
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
<%include file="special_message.html" />
```

you can turn the message *on* by putting the message HTML into the file.

And you can turn the message *off* by clearing the file:

```
echo > special_message.html
```

or

```
with open('special_message', 'w') as f:
    f.write('')
```